# Inner joining multiple columns to one ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm not in charge of the database so I can't change the format, I realize it is a horrible database.

I have two tables I want to join:

**Table1: address_book**

```
id | name | address | phone number | email
```

**Table2: team**

```
id | person1_id | person2_id | person3_id | person4_id | person5_id | person6_id
```

I would like to join all the personX_id with the name from address_book. I can't seem to figure out how to join more than one column. Hoping someone here could help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you have only 6 colums for person_id you could use a multiple join

```
  select a1.name 
  from team t 
  left  join address_book a1 on a1.name = t.person1_id 
  left  join address_book a2 on a2.name = t.person2_id 
  left  join address_book a3 on a3.name = t.person3_id 
  left  join address_book a4 on a4.name = t.person4_id 
  left  join address_book a5 on a5.name = t.person5_id 
  left  join address_book a6 on a6.name = t.person6_id
```